# Advanced tool for optimizing T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a tool which can look at your T-SQL and suggest hints for better performance? For example it finds usage of SARGs and converts a query into one without use of a sarg. Or pinpointing inefficient use of joins.

I am looking for tools beyond the Database Engine Tuning Advisor & use of the Profiler. For example I am currently checking out Toad for SQL Server which has some optimization features.

**Addition:**

Toad has an optimizer where it creates different queries or scenarios for my query and evaluates the cost of each query but its suggestions are primitive & simple. It's in the right direction but hopefully the optimizer gets a lot more smarter over time and be more useful.

Comment: should this tool also tell you how to change your schema?  how about your network?  how about your application architecture?  perhaps you are expecting too much from the SQL.

Comment: @randy Nope.. I am happy with the couple of the examples I mentioned. Those shouldn't be impossible cases. You can't know everything out there if you don't ask.

Comment: Wouldn't a tool that replaces SARGs with non-SARGable expressions be a de-optimizer?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You want to avoid SARGs which means when you avoid them, you're optimizing your query. http://bit.ly/jIgYSZ

Comment: that's *not* what that article is highlighting at all. In that particular case, it's highlighting that SQL Server is unable to implicitly convert an nvarchar back to varchar, which *would* have made the query SARGable. You *want* SARGable queries - otherwise the only strategy available to SQL Server is scans.

Answer (score 3):

While it won't cook breakfast nor repair your automobile, the LessThanDot SqlCop can highlight some wayward database code and objects which have an effect on performance. It is a best practices analyzer that is more application-oriented than the Microsoft Best Practices Analyzer (which is more DBA-oriented). The price is nice for both of them (free).

Check them out for yourself...

- [**LessThanDot SqlCop**](http://sqlcop.lessthandot.com/)
- [**MS Best Practices Analyzer**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0fd439d7-4bff-4df7-a52f-9a1be8725591&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of static analysis tools for T-SQL which can identify the types of problems you're interested in detecting, although they will not suggest detailed fixes.

[SQL Enlight](http://www.ubitsoft.com/products/sqlenlight/sqlenlight.php) offers 80+ pre-defined static analysis rules plus the ability to define your own - it will run as an SSMS plugin and a command-line tool. There's also a limited version on the website.

The Visual Studio editions which include the database tools also include fewer (20 or so) static analysis rules for T-SQL. Using it requires importing your code into a VS database project.